# Fire event only when the user is done dragging the trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I have a trackbar control which fires the scroll event every time i move the slider. Is there any way to make it fire only when the user is done dragging it?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @Colin Laws for the answear. I did it like that:

```
  bool volChanged = false;
    private void volumeBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        volChanged = true;                   
    }

    private void volumeBar_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (volChanged == true)
        {
            volChanged = false;
            //PUT HERE THE CODE TO EXECUTE
        }
```

It is not the most efficient way but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Mouse Events that are on all WinForms controls to achieve this.

The OnMouseUp event is what you're looking for. See the following documentation for more help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/handling-user-input#mouse-events